# How to properly chain promises?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm having issues using promises in javascript (es6).

So far I've used promises but not so extensively, and in this project I need to chain promises inside others, and make sure to wait one to conclude before I continue with the rest of the tasks.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
myArray = ['element1', 'element2', /*...*/]
const function1 = () => {
    return function2()
             .then(() => {
                 console.log('first to fire')
                 return myArray
                     .reduce(async(previousPromise, element) => {
                          console.log('reduce', element)
                          await previousPromise
                          return function3(element)
                     }, Promise.resolve())
             })
             .then(() => {
                 console.log('this should fire last but actually fires before the last function3() is done')
             })
}
/*
function1 => the function I'm trying to create, which should return a promise. 

function2 => an external function that I have no control. this function
is asynchronous and returns a promise.

function3 => this is also an asynchronous external function that
returns a promise that I should execute to get what I need. It 
receives as parameter a value which I have in myArray, and it should
execute successively one after the other (for example as if 'element2'
was dependent of 'element1', and so on). 
*/
```

somehow I'm not chaining this promise properly as the result I'm getting is (myArray with only 2 elements):

```
>first to fire
>reduce element1
>reduce element2
>this should fire last but actually fires before the last function3() is done
>a log I've added inside of function3 which corresponds to 'element1'
>a log I've added inside of function3 which corresponds to 'element2'
```

So... Basically I need everything to 'wait' until all the promises are done with their work. How should I properly do that?

Comment: If you're able to use `async` and `await`, why are you making a nesting mess with `.then`? Provide a concrete input and expected output. Please paste real code instead of renaming everything to `function1`, `function2` - this makes it much harder for readers to reason about what the program is meant to do.

Comment: `function3()` being nested inside `function2()` is probably the issue. That would break the chain because the next then will execute when `function2()` completes.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. It should do what you need.

Comment: Ie, "...returns a promise," - a promise of what? `undefined`? All of these empty `()` are code smell that you're using promises incorrectly. A promise represents a future _value_. What I'm seeing here is some misunderstood application of promises as some sort of "callback"

Comment: Please post your implementation of `function3`.

Comment: Wait, what is that `resolve()` call as the argument to `reduce`? Did you mean `Promise.resolve()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why your code wouldn't work (most likely the problem is inside `function3`, which fulfills its returned promise too early), but you should try to keep it simple:

```
async function function1() {
    await function2();
    console.log('first to fire')
    for (const element of myArray) {
        console.log('loop', element);
        await function3(element);
    }
    console.log('last to fire');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to simplify like you suggested and now it is working well

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `await` to get the result from function3. You also need to use `async` when declaring your new function. Working example:

```js
myArray = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']

const function1 = async() => {
  return function2()
    .then(async(results) => {
      console.log('first to fire with ' + results)
      return await myArray.reduce(async(accumP, element) => {
        console.log('reduce', element)
        return await accumP + await function3(results, element)
      }, Promise.resolve(''))
    })
    .then((finalResults) => {
      console.log('this should fire last... and does, with ' + JSON.stringify(finalResults))
    })
}

const function2 = async() => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve('foo '), 10))

const function3 = async(prefix, element) => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(prefix + element + ' bar, '), 50))

function1()
```

As others have noted in the comments, if you are able to use `await` anyway, you could greatly simplify things for yourself in understanding this by never using `then` and always using `await`.

```js
myArray = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']

const function1 = async() => {
  const f2results = await function2()

  const f3results = await myArray.reduce(async(accumP, element) => {
    console.log('reduce', element)
    return await accumP + await function3(f2results, element)
  }, Promise.resolve(''))

  console.log('this should fire last... and does, with ' + JSON.stringify(f3results))
}

const function2 = async() => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve('foo '), 10))

const function3 = async(prefix, element) => new Promise((resolve) =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(prefix + element + ' bar, '), 50))

function1()
```